# Add number after the name of a directory who already exist

Tags: python, plugins, pyqgis

For my QGIS Plugin, I would like to write a python script who add a serial number after the name of a directory if this directory already exist same way as windows do when you download the same file several times. But I don't know how to achieve this.

For example:

If the directory `'C:/Dossier'` already exist, the new directory will be `'C:/Dossier(1)'` and so on.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this where `path_to_dir` is the target you want to create.

```py
 import os
 count=0
 if os.path.exists(path_to_dir):
     # start while (adding "(count)" to string)
     while True:
         new_dir_name=path_to_dir+f'({count})'
         if os.path.exists(new_dir_name):
             count+=1
         else:
             os.mkdir(new_dir_name)
             break
 else:
     os.mkdir(path_to_dir)
```

Comment: Then why you don't upvote the answer and mark it as accepted? That's how SO works, and that's how you better acknowledge people who solves questions.